# Does if-else python short-cut evaluate function twice?

Tags: python, nonetype

Let's say I have a function `getQ(x)` which returns some number and it is pretty slow. Now, if I do this:

```
x = 10
x = getQ(x) if getQ(x) >= 0 else 0
```

does `getQ` get executed twice in such case?

Is this:

```
x = getQ(x)
x = x if x >= 0 else 0
```

quicker?

If so, is there a more elegant one-liner for such a situation?

Comment: You could try it by adding a `print` statement inside the function `getQ()`

Comment: @Christian Ha, yep, good idea, now I know, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `getQ` would be called twice if the result is nonnegative, so the second would definitely be quicker in that case.

In this particular case, you could write `x = max(getQ(x), 0)`. The "general" solution you're looking for is something like

```
x = (lambda x: x if x >= 0 else 0)(getQ(x))
```

I wouldn't recommend using this in real code, but it lets you bind a name while still keeping it one expression.

Comment: Heh, if that would be only `max` I needed. Nice idea anyway, I thought maybe there is some expansion of it with using lambda-function, but can't quite come up with it... Maybe there is none. I'm just having a few of those things in my code and these flattened if-else's don't look readable to me - I just want to have this kind of default value function would collapse to in case if the result is not what I want... assuming I don't want to touch the function itself.

Comment: Well, I suppose you could write something like `x = (lambda x: x if x >= 0 else 0)(getQ(x))`. I wouldn't like to see code like this in real life though :s

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Can you please add it to your answer - I know this is not very pretty at all, but would be the actual answer to the question, nevertheless.

Comment: Actually, it is not that ugly because it merely collapses those two lines of code I have to one. You immediately know it is applied to getQ(x) and doesn't use any intermediate steps. I kind of like it, lucky for you, you aren't going to read my code :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `dis` module and clearly see that the function would be called twice in first case.

```
def fun1():
    ...:     x = sqrt(10) if sqrt(10)>=0 else 0
    ...:     

dis.dis(fun1)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sqrt) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (10) 
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)  // First Call
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (0) 
             12 COMPARE_OP               5 (>=) 
             15 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       30 
             18 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sqrt) 
             21 LOAD_CONST               1 (10) 
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) // Second Call
             27 JUMP_FORWARD             3 (to 33) 
        >>   30 LOAD_CONST               2 (0) 
        >>   33 STORE_FAST               0 (x) 
             36 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             39 RETURN_VALUE         



def fun2():
    x = sqrt(10)
    x = x if x>=10 else 0



dis.dis(fun2)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sqrt) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (10) 
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) // Single call
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (x) 

  3          12 LOAD_FAST                0 (x) 
             15 LOAD_CONST               1 (10) 
             18 COMPARE_OP               5 (>=) 
             21 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       30 
             24 LOAD_FAST                0 (x) 
             27 JUMP_FORWARD             3 (to 33) 
        >>   30 LOAD_CONST               2 (0) 
        >>   33 STORE_FAST               0 (x) 
             36 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             39 RETURN_VALUE
```